# How to handle rotations based on a quat camera?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm having a problem with getting rotations based on mouse movement.

I use a camera class similar to this:
http://hamelot.io/visualization/moderngl-camera/

Here is the code:

```
#include "Camera.h"

#include <gl/glew.h>

#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include <SFML/Window/Keyboard.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Mouse.hpp>


Camera::Camera() : _viewportX(0), _viewportY(0), _windowX(1920), _windowY(1080), _lastX(0), _lastY(0), _aspect(1), _nearClip(.001f), _farClip(1000.0f), _cameraHeading(0), _cameraPitch(0), _grab(false)
{
    _cameraType = CameraType::FREE;
    _cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    _fov = 45.0f;
    _cameraPosDelta = glm::vec3(0);
    _cameraScale = 0.01f;
    _maxPitch = 5;
    _maxHeading = 5;
    _moveCamera = false;

}

Camera::~Camera()
{
}

void Camera::reset()
{
    _cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

void Camera::update()
{
    _oldDirection = _cameraDirection;
    _cameraDirection = glm::normalize(_cameraLookAt - _cameraPos);
    // We need to set the matrix state, this is important because lighting won't work otherwise
    glViewport(_viewportX, _viewportY, _windowX, _windowY);

    if (_cameraType == CameraType::ORTHO)
    {
        _projection = glm::ortho(-1.5f * float(_aspect), 1.5f * float(_aspect), -1.5f, 1.5f, -10.0f, 10.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        _projection = glm::perspective(_fov, _aspect, _nearClip, _farClip);
        // Axis for pitch rotation
        glm::vec3 axis = glm::cross(_cameraDirection, _cameraUp);
        // Compute quaternion for pitch based on the camera pitch angle
        glm::quat pitchQuat = glm::angleAxis(_cameraPitch, axis);
        // Determine heading quaternion from the camera up vector and the heading angle
        glm::quat headingQuat = glm::angleAxis(_cameraHeading, _cameraUp);
        // Add the two quats
        glm::quat tempQuat = glm::cross(pitchQuat, headingQuat);
        tempQuat = glm::normalize(tempQuat);
        // Update the direction from the quaternion 
        _cameraDirection = glm::rotate(tempQuat, _cameraDirection);
        // add the camera delta
        _cameraPos += _cameraPosDelta;
        // set the lookat matrix to be infront of the camera
        _cameraLookAt = _cameraPos + _cameraDirection * 1.0f;
        // Damping for smooth camera
        _cameraHeading *= 0.5f;
        _cameraPitch *= 0.5f;
        _cameraPosDelta *= 0.8f;
    }
    // compute the mvp
    _view = glm::lookAt(_cameraPos, _cameraLookAt, _cameraUp);
}

void Camera::moveKeyboard()
{
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Q))
        processMovement(UP);
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::E))
        processMovement(DOWN);
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
        processMovement(LEFT);
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
        processMovement(RIGHT);
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
        processMovement(FORWARD);
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
        processMovement(BACK);


}

void Camera::changePitch(float degrees)
{
    //Check bounds with the max pitch rate so that we aren't moving too fast
    if (degrees < -_maxPitch)
    {
        degrees = -_maxPitch;
    }
    else if (degrees > _maxPitch)
    {
        degrees = _maxPitch;
    }
    _cameraPitch += degrees;

    // Check bounds for cameraPitch
    if (_cameraPitch > 360.0f)
    {
        _cameraPitch -= 360.0f;
    }
    else if (_cameraPitch < -360.0f)
    {
        _cameraPitch += 360.0f;
    }
}

void Camera::changeHeading(float degrees)
{
    //Check bounds with the max Heading rate so that we aren't moving too fast
    if (degrees < -_maxHeading)
    {
        degrees = -_maxHeading;
    }
    else if (degrees > _maxHeading)
    {
        degrees = _maxHeading;
    }
    _cameraHeading += degrees;

    // This controls how the heading is changed if the camera is pointed straight up or down
    // The heading delta direction changes
    if (_cameraPitch > 90 && _cameraPitch < 270 || (_cameraPitch < -90 && _cameraPitch > -270))
    {
        _cameraHeading -= degrees;
    }
    else
    {
        _cameraHeading += degrees;
    }

    // Check bounds for cameraHeading
    if (_cameraHeading > 360.0f)
    {
        _cameraHeading -= 360.0f;
    }
    else if (_cameraHeading < -360.0f)
    {
        _cameraHeading += 360.0f;
    }
}

void Camera::processMouseMovement(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    auto mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
    if (_lastX == 0 && _lastY == 0)
    {
        _lastX = _windowX / 2;
        _lastY = _windowY / 2;
    }
    if (mousePos != sf::Vector2i(_lastX, _lastY))
    {
        GLfloat xOffset = (_windowX / 2) - mousePos.x;
        GLfloat yOffset = (_windowY / 2) - mousePos.y;
        xOffset *= _cameraScale;
        yOffset *= _cameraScale;
        if (_moveCamera)
        {
            changeHeading(.08f * xOffset);
            changePitch(.08f * yOffset);
        }
    }
    sf::Mouse::setPosition(sf::Vector2i(_windowX / 2, _windowY / 2), window);
}

void Camera::setMode(CameraType type)
{
    _cameraType = type;
    _cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

void Camera::setPosition(glm::vec3 pos)
{
    _cameraPos = pos;
}

void Camera::setLookAt(glm::vec3 pos)
{
    _cameraLookAt = pos;
}

void Camera::setFOV(double fov)
{
    _fov = fov;
}

void Camera::setViewport(int locX, int locY, int width, int height)
{
    _viewportX = locX;
    _viewportY = locY;
    _windowX = width;
    _windowY = height;
    _aspect = static_cast<double>(_windowX) / static_cast<double>(_windowY);
}

void Camera::setClipping(double nearClipDistance, double farClipDistance)
{
    _nearClip = nearClipDistance;
    _farClip = farClipDistance;
}

void Camera::processMouseButtons()
{
    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left))
    {
        _moveCamera = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _moveCamera = false;
    }
    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Right))
    {
        _grab = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _grab = false;
    }
}

CameraType Camera::getMode()
{
    return _cameraType;
}

void Camera::getViewPort(int& locX, int& locY, int& width, int& height)
{
    locX = _viewportX;
    locY = _viewportY;
    width = _windowX;
    height = _windowY;

}

void Camera::getMatrices(glm::mat4& view, glm::mat4& projection)
{
    projection = _projection;
    view = _view;
}

void Camera::processMovement(CameraDirection direction)
{
    if (_cameraType == FREE)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
        case UP:
            _cameraPosDelta -= _cameraUp * _cameraScale;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            _cameraPosDelta += _cameraUp * _cameraScale;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            _cameraPosDelta -= glm::cross(_cameraDirection, _cameraUp) * _cameraScale;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            _cameraPosDelta += glm::cross(_cameraDirection, _cameraUp) * _cameraScale;
            break;
        case FORWARD:
            _cameraPosDelta += _cameraDirection * _cameraScale;
            break;
        case BACK:
            _cameraPosDelta -= _cameraDirection * _cameraScale;
            break;
        case DEFAULT:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a model rotate based on the camera direction (or lookAt). I've done the basics like:

```
float xRot = glm::dot(_oldDirection.x, _cameraDirection.x);
xRot = acos(xRot);
```

This gives me the angle of the two vectors, and i plug that into my model rotation:

```
        model[1][1] *= cos(xRot * (PI / 180));
        model[2][1] *= -sin(xRot * (PI / 180));
        model[1][2] *= sin(xRot * (PI / 180));
        model[2][2] *= cos(xRot * (PI / 180));
```

The problems i'm facing are:

- The model rotates about 7x the amount of a my movements. If i move the mouse 180 degrees, the model will rotate 7 times that amount.
- The model locks up if i rotate too much in one direction, to fix it i have to rotate the other direction.
- A unrelated problem with the camera class : I'm getting a form of gimbal lock. If i move the mouse very fast downward ( i mean i have to thrust it as hard as i can downward) The screen will turn grey and the screen/camera will lock up. The same happens when i thrust the mouse upwards, I can't I think the sides don't gimbal lock.

If you could link me to any resources or help me out, that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calculating a quaternion from heading/pitch/roll angles, which is the wrong order. To use a quaternion for smooth camera movement, the mouse/keyboard/whatever controls continually update a quaternion. When you draw, convert this quaternion into a matrix and use that for the camera orientation. (Quat -> rotation matrix should be part of your 3D maths library.)

Search "Ken Shoemake quaternion" for explanations and sample code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a good and simple way to implement an exclusively quaternion based camera. Surprisingly I couldn't find any good implementation in glm so here it goes.

principles.
 - accumulate the frame pitch yaw and roll separately.
 - calculate the yaw(x) in world space and the pitch(x) and roll(z) in local(default) space.

```
void Render::Node::setRotationByXYZ(float inX, float inY, float inZ) {

  x += inX/100;
  y += inY/100;
  z += inZ/100;

  glm::quat qX = normalize(glm::quat(cos(x/2), sin(x/2), 0, 0));
  glm::quat qY = normalize(glm::quat(cos(y/2), 0, sin(y/2), 0));
  glm::quat qZ = normalize(glm::quat(cos(z/2), 0, 0, sin(z/2)));

  glm::quat qXWorld = glm::inverse(glm::quat(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0))*qX;
  glm::quat q = qXWorld*qZ*qY;

  this->rotation = q;
}
```

So normally you would convert to matrix and transform by identity matrix, but using the quat identity value works just the same.
If you don't need roll, just omit qZ. This works for me but your multiplication order may differ of course.
This is by far the simplest approach I could come up with, I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might find useful is an alternative to glm::lookAt:

```cpp
void Camera::lookAt(Quaternion rot, Vertex Pos)
{
    view = Matrix<4>();

    Vertex v1 = (rot*Vertex(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f)).normalize(); // forward
    Vertex v2 = (rot*Vertex(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f)).normalize().cross(v1); // up
    Vertex v3 = v1.cross(v2);

    view[0][0] = v2.x;
    view[0][1] = v3.x;
    view[0][2] = v1.x;

    view[1][0] = v2.y;
    view[1][1] = v3.y;
    view[1][2] = v1.y;

    view[2][0] = v2.z;
    view[2][1] = v3.z;
    view[2][2] = v1.z;

    view[3][0] = -v2.dot(Pos);
    view[3][1] = -v3.dot(Pos);
    view[3][2] = -v1.dot(Pos);
    //Comment this out if you aren't using the left hand coordinate system
    view = view.transpose();
}
```

Massive thanks to joe stevens for mentioning this method: http://joestevens.net/post/20063172257/alternate-view-matrix-construction

I rewrote this for my own purposes, but check out the original by any means.

You can then just feed your camera the Quaternion and its Center position and it will churn out a nice view matrix. 
This means that you can simply add your yaw,pitch,roll to the quaternion each time that you rotate, or even better use the quaternion as your source of rotations.